# mysql SELECT and summarize if column not null

Tags: mysql

I don't know if this is possible with mySQL but I want to return a `true|false` value if a column is not null.

Suppose you have this data:

```
 ------------------------------------
| id | path        | tags            |
 ------------------------------------
| 1  | img-001.jpg | cats,animals    |
| 2  | img-002.jpg | baby,family,boy |
| 3  | img-003.jpg | null            |
| 4  | img-004.jpg | cars            |
 ------------------------------------
```

I'd like to `SELECT` to get a results array something like:

```
{id:1, path:img-001.jpg, hasTag: true},
{id:2, path:img-002.jpg, hasTag: true},
{id:3, path:img-003.jpg, hasTag: false},
{id:4, path:img-004.jpg, hasTag: true}
```

Can mySQL do that for me without needing the application to iterate over the data?

Comment: Admittedly I'm more familiar with T-SQL, but from a quick search it seems like MySQL has a similar `CASE` syntax: `SELECT id, path, CASE WHEN tags IS NOT NULL THEN true ELSE false END AS hasTag`.  [[**Documentation**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html)]

Comment: Like @TylerRoper mentioned, MySQL does support `CASE WHEN ... END CASE`. Official documentation [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this sort of [ternary if statement](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_if.asp) might work:

```
SELECT
    id
    , path
    , IF(tags is null, FALSE, TRUE) as hasTag
FROM
    ...
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `IFNULL()` with select. Like.

```
SELECT id, path, (case when (IFNULL(tags, false) = false) then false else true END) as hasTag from tableA ;
```

Change the `tableA` with your actual table name.

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation of MYSQL

> The ISNULL() function returns 1 or 0 depending on whether an
>   expression is NULL

According to description as mentioned above as a solution to it,please try executing following SQL select statement.

```
SELECT id,path,IF(ISNULL(tags),false,true) as hasTag FROM `table`
```